# Problems returning csv data, pentaho reading failure

Tags: csv, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I found this repository on github when I was looking for solutions and here are some dependencies that look like I need them

https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/trans/steps/csvinput/CsvInput.java

which contains some code for the dependencies I need, but I don't know where to organize it in my pentaho folder or where to include it, of course, after this error I went looking for solutions that appear to be my solution, but I will immediately forward my settings in pentaho , path of the csv that I am forwarding to the pentaho csv input and the error that I am receiving. I would like some help to resolve this error

```
2024/02/15 13:17:15 - RepositoriesMeta - Reading repositories XML file: C:\Users\mlinhares\.kettle\repositories.xml
2024/02/15 13:17:15 - RepositoriesMeta - Reading repositories XML file: C:\Users\mlinhares\.kettle\repositories.xml
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - Spoon - Transformation opened.
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - Spoon - Launching transformation [Transformação 1]...
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - Spoon - Started the transformation execution.
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - Transformação 1 - Expedindo in�cio para transforma��o [Transformação 1]
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - CSV file input.0 - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : Erro inicializando step [CSV file input]
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - CSV file input.0 - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfileinput.EncodingType
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - CSV file input.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.csvinput.CsvInput.init(CsvInput.java:898)
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - CSV file input.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.StepInitThread.run(StepInitThread.java:69)
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - CSV file input.0 -    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - CSV file input.0 - Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'byte[] org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.byteArray(int)' [in thread "init of CSV file input.0 (Thread-11)"]
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - CSV file input.0 -    at org.apache.commons.io.ByteOrderMark.getBytes(ByteOrderMark.java:125)
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - CSV file input.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfileinput.EncodingType.<clinit>(EncodingType.java:39)
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - CSV file input.0 -    ... 3 more
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - Transformação 1 - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : Step [CSV file input.0] falhou durante inicializa��o!
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - Spoon - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : Transformação 1: preparing transformation execution failed
2024/02/15 13:18:08 - Spoon - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkYna.png)

I was hoping to be able to return the csv data, but it returned me this log with some reading details

Comment: better to use the standard text input. It is perfect to use with csv. Can you explain which functionalities you need which you can't find in that step? Then we can help you out. The defect is somewhere in the middle of the custom step. Might take forever to find and fix.

Comment: I'm trying to use the csv input component which is giving me this error:

Comment: I added the image to the description with the component configured